# React Routes: 404page is always shown at the bottom of all pages of the site, except for the main page

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, react-router-dom

I need to display a custom 404 page if there is no such page on the site. For this, the `<Route path='*' element={<MissingPage />} />` route is introduced and it manages this matter. BUT apart from this, 404 page is displayed at the bottom on all pages on the site, except for the main one. I wish it didn't show up

```
"dependencies":
  "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
  "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
  "react": "^18.1.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.1.0",

"devDependencies":
  "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
```

Bottom is an example of one of the routes

Others are similar to this one, at the end the route to the main page is inserted along the path "/" and 404 along the path "*"

[Already tried 'exact' property. Unfortunately, it remained in the old versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InldH.png)

```
return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <SharedContextProvider>
            <div className='main'>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <SharedDataManagement>
                        <Fragment>
                            <AuthRoutes />
                            <DashboardRoutes />
                            <SubscriptionsContextProvider>
                                <SubscriptionsRoutes />
                            </SubscriptionsContextProvider>
                            <PaymentRoutes />
                            <CommitmentRoutes />
                            <CoursesRoutes />
                            <ContactUsRoutes />
                            <ErrorsRoutes />
                            <Routes>
                                <Route path='/' element={<HomePageComponent />} />
                                <Route path='*' element={<MissingPage />} />
                            </Routes>
                        </Fragment>
                    </SharedDataManagement>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        </SharedContextProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

...

```
export function PaymentRoutes() {
    return (
        <PaymentContextProvider>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/payment' element={<PaymentPage />} />
                <Route path='/payment/success' element={<SubscriptionPage />} />
            </Routes>
        </PaymentContextProvider>
    )
}
```

...

```
export function CommitmentRoutes() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/privacy-policy' element={<PrivacyPolicyPage />} />
            <Route path='/terms-and-conditions' element={<TermsAndConditionsPage />} />
            <Route path='/cookie' element={<CookiePage />} />
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you rendering multiple sets of `Routes` components all at the same time? I.E. the `AuthRoutes`, `DashboardRoutes`, etc... Can you include all relevant code in your question? See [mcve]. Each custom "routes" component needs to be rendered on a route, and you should be aware that each `Routes` component should have its own "404" route.

Comment: @Drew Reese, Yes, all components with "routes" in their name are bundles of routes. I already tried the option in which each pack of routes has its own 404 route, then the 404 page was also displayed on all pages, including the main one, and several times

Answer (score 1):

You could use react-router [Switch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component to render only one route per url :

```
return (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <HomePageComponent />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/my-first-path">
      <MyFirstComponent />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/my-second-path">
      <MySecondComponent />
    </Route>
    <Route>
      <MissingPage />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);
```

Comment: unfortunately this is version 6 of routes, there is no switch here

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@6`, so there is no `Switch` component. It was replaced by the `Routes` component.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The issue is that the code is rendering several sets of `Routes` components via the custom routes components ***as well as*** the final `Routes` that is rendering a "404" route. The last `Routes` is always rendered and when it doesn't render a route that matches the current URL it renders its "404" route.

## Solution

I suggest converting all the custom routes components into layout route components and render all the routes into a single `Routes` component with the single "404" route.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export function PaymentLayout() {
  return (
    <PaymentContextProvider>
      <Outlet />
    </PaymentContextProvider>
  )
}
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <SharedDataManagement>
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
        ....
      </Route>
      <Route element={<DashboardLayout />}>
        ....
      </Route>
      <Route element={<SubscriptionsLayout />}>
        ....
      </Route>
      <Route element={<PaymentLayout />}>
        <Route path='/payment' element={<PaymentPage />} />
        <Route path='/payment/success' element={<SubscriptionPage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route element={<CommitmentLayout />}>
        <Route path='/privacy-policy' element={<PrivacyPolicyPage />} />
        <Route path='/terms-and-conditions' element={<TermsAndConditionsPage />} />
        <Route path='/cookie' element={<CookiePage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route element={<CoursesLayout />}>
        ....
      </Route>
      <Route element={<ContactUsLayout />}>
        ....
      </Route>
      <Route element={<ErrorsLayout />}>
        ....
      </Route> 
      <Route path='/' element={<HomePageComponent />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<MissingPage />} />
    </Routes>
  </SharedDataManagement>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, however, I found another solution, now I'll show it

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

The issue is that the code is rendering several sets of Routes components via the custom routes components as well as the final Routes that is rendering a "404" route. The last Routes is always rendered and when it doesn't render a route that matches the current URL it renders its "404" route.

#### Solution

I was already given a solution, but it was important for me to set the project structure in its current form.

Therefore, for starters, I found the config.ts file
here I entered all my routes as an array of strings

```
export const knownRoutes: string[] = [
    ...
    'payment', 
    'success', 
    'login' , 
    'register', 
    ...
]
```

Then I introduced the unknown route logic

```
export function App() {
    const isUnknownRoutes = knownRoutes.find((route) => (window.location.href).includes(route))
    
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <SharedContextProvider>
                <div className='main'>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <SharedDataManagement>
                            <Fragment>
                                <AuthRoutes />
                                <DashboardRoutes />
                                <SubscriptionsContextProvider>
                                    <SubscriptionsRoutes />
                                </SubscriptionsContextProvider>
                                <PaymentRoutes />
                                ...
                                <Routes>
                                    <Route path='/' element={<HomePageComponent />} />
                                    {!isUnknownRoutes && (<Route path='*' element={<MissingPage />} />)}
                                </Routes>
                            </Fragment>
                        </SharedDataManagement>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </div>
            </SharedContextProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

Comment: If this is the solution you'd prefer then I'd suggest elevating `BrowserRouter` to wrap this `App` component and use the [matchPath](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/utils/match-path) function from RRD and iterate over the array of known route paths and check if any return a non-null value. I.E. something like `const { pathname } = useLocation(); const isUnknownRoot = !knownRoutes.some(route => matchPath(route, pathname));`.

Comment: @Drew Reese, Thank you! I understand what you are talking about, your solution looks more elegant